# Settings default font in gvim

Tags: vim, x11

I'm using gvim (vim -g). I want to set default font to be Monaco.

Here is the content of my .vimrc

```
if has("gui_running")
    if has("gui_gtk2")
         set guifont=Monaco\ New\ 11
       elseif has("gui_photon")
         set guifont=Monaco\ New:s11
       elseif has("gui_kde")
         set guifont=Monaco\ New/11/-1/5/50/0/0/0/1/0
       elseif has("x11")
         "set guifont=-*-courier-medium-r-normal-*-*-180-*-*-m-*-*
         set guifont=Monaco:h11:cDEFAULT

       else
         set guifont=Monaco:h11:cDEFAULT
     endif
  endif
```

When I start gvim the font is not Monaco

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The easiest way of setting the `'guifont'` is simply not bothering with the exact font string at all.

Use a friendly dialog to set it instead:

```
:set guifont=*
```

This pops up a dialog where you can select your preferred font.

Once you have set it, you can query the setting again with

```
:set guifont?
```

and put *that* string in your vimrc. On my machine this returns `Monaco:h12` for Monaco at 12pt. Make the change at the appropriate place in your block, or, if you have no idea what you're doing, simply replace the whole block with

```
if has("gui_running")
  set guifont=Monaco:h12
endif
```

Comment: I did what you suggest but when I start gvim the font is not Monaco. When I type :set guifont? I get guifont=Monaco:h10 which is strange..

Comment: Did you put this bit `set guifont=Monaco:h10` in your vimrc? Is it perhaps overwritten somewhere down the line? What does `:verbose set gfn?` output?

Comment: It says guifont=Monaco 10
You can see my .vimrc file here - http://pastebin.com/Ae7Dqum1

Comment: Good tip on how to copy paste the output of `:set guifont?`: http://superuser.com/questions/167352/how-do-i-copy-command-output-in-vim

Comment: invoking "set guifont?" doesn't save this in .vimrc so after restart we go to same font as before.

Answer (score 15):

set guifont=Font\ Name\ Size

Replace the spaces by '\ '

Comment: Thanks. set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono\ Book\ 12

Comment: That backslash is essential.  And it's not output by `set guifont?`.

Comment: This should be proper accepted answer, all other just do not work.
putting `set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ 15` in ~/.vimrc worked for me

Comment: 8 years later and this little tidbit saved my day! Clearly deserving of stronger visibility.