# Cannot set the default font of gvim in mint

Tags: vim, fonts, linux-mint

i have tried to move my configuration of VIM in Mac to Linux Mint.

However, the default font of gvim cannot be set. I have already put `set guifont=Monaco:h14` into my **.vimrc** and I have also downloaded the font into my system. I have checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882696/settings-default-font-in-gvim), the `verbose` command can be used to find the setting of **gui_font**. I used the `verbose` command and the result pointed to my **.vimrc**.

The most interesting part is that I can set the gui font by the **same command**: `set guifont=Monaco:h14` in the running environment of gvim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong format.

This format:

```
set guifont=Monaco:h14
```

is for Mac OS X while you should use:

```
set guifont=Monaco\ 14
```

on Linux.

Everything is explained very clearly in `:help 'guifont'`.

Hint #1: you can do `:set guifont=*` to open a GUI dialog, once you have chosen your font you can simply do `:set guifont` to see the correct string to use in your `~/.vimrc`. Don't forget to escape spaces.

Hint #2: [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17019050/546861) shows you how to make different platform-specific settings.