# GUI applications messed up in Cygwin X

Tags: cygwin, xorg

I have installed gvim, xinit, xorg-server in my cygwin installation.
When I start 'XWin Server' and then a Cygwin terminal (DISPLAY=:0.0), I am able to open gvim.

But the visual quality is pathetic. Characters appear half-rendered and choppy looking.

For example, the colorscheme command in gvim's command bar

[image: For example, the colorscheme command in gvim's command bar]

[EDIT - Adding one more screenshot]
Looks like redrawing/rendering is the issue here. As I type in vim, the cursor 'imprints' are left behind on top of characters.
[image]

The font is Monospace 10 and font itself renders correctly.

Comment: Font? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882696/settings-default-font-in-gvim

Comment: I did not change any font related settings. Everything is default. Is there a particular font I must choose?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with Monospace font.
Install some fonts and make your tests, gvim by default does not pull the installation of any font.

[image]

Comment: Monospace size 10 is exactly what mine is set to (by default) as well. The font renders correctly. The real issue is redrawing doesn't seem to be happening properly. For instance, as I type and as the cursor box moves ahead, its "imprint" is left behind overlapping on the characters messing them up. Then when I move to new line, previous line looks good. And so on. Anyway, I decided to chuck Cygwin altogether, installed Debian in VirtualBox and I am happy.